# How to fix the working panels in pgadmin 4

Tags: pgadmin

Hello I'm beginner and I'm having a problem fixing the working panels (eg. query tool, scratch pad and data output panel), as you can see in the screenshot everytime i resize pgadmin all 3 modules goes everywhere.  any tips??
Thank you[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok nevermind i figured i can just simply go to File - Reset Layout.